# One field xml cannot be deserialized using XmlSerializer class

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I have the following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<connection_state>conn_state</connection_state>
```

Following the msdn, I must describe it as a type for correct deserialization using XmlSerializer. So the class name points the first tag, and its fields subtags.
For example:

```
public class connection_state
{
   public string state;
}
```

Will be transformed into the following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<connection_state>
    <state>conn_state</state>
</connection_state>
```

But the xml I receive has only one tag. And we cannot create a field with the name of its class like:

```
public class connection_state
{
    public string connection_state;
}
```

Or can?
Is there any solution for this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Proper Xml has a root element with no content except other elements. If you are stuck with that tiny one-tag psuedo-XML, is there a reason you need to use XmlSerializer? Why not just create a class with a constructor that takes the literal "Xml" string:

```
using System.Xml.Linq;

public class connection_state {
    public string state { get; set; }
    public connection_state(string xml) {
        this.state = XDocument.Parse(xml).Element("connection_state").Value;
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

In response to OP's comment: You don't *have* to us an XmlSerializer; you can just read the ResponseStream directly and pass that to your `connection_state` constructor:

```
String xmlString = (new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream())).ReadToEnd();
connection_state c= new connection_state(xmlString);
```

Comment: I need XmlSerializer, because I receive this xml body in WebResponse for my WebRequest.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
public class connection_state
{
   public string state;
}
```

to

```
public class connection_state
{
   public string state {set; get;}
}
```

Comment: It was shown as example of full xml. And in my case I have one-tag xml (only "connection_state" tag). I have no "state" field in it.